# Как разархивировать архив содержащий длинные пути?

Tags: windows-8, архивация, rar

Имеется архив, который при обычной разархивации выдает что у файлов слишком длинные пути, как решить данную проблему ?
ОС:Windows 8(64bit)

Comment: "при обычной разархивации" каким архиватором? Какой версии?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Пробовал WinRAR-ом, это не сколько архиватор, это сколько сама ОС ругается.

Comment: Потому что архиватор неправильно с ней работает.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов а какое решение посоветуете ?

Comment: Посоветую пробовать другие архиваторы.